# create dataframe from text r

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a text file with more than a million lines of text. There are three columns, person 1, person 2, and year. I want to extract all these values and want to make a data frame. But, don't know how to do it. Please help me in this regard.

```
[1] "[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Mary F. Fernandez\", 1998],"    
[2] "[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Daniela Florescu\", 1998],"     
[3] "[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Alon Y. Levy\", 1998],"         
[4] "[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Dan Suciu\", 1998],"            
[5] "[\"Mary F. Fernandez\", \"Daniela Florescu\", 1998],"
```

I want to extract all these values and want to make a data frame. But, don't know how to do it. Please help me in this regard. The output should be a data frame with three columns i.e., person1, person2, and year as follows.

```
Person1             Person2             Year
Alin Deutsch        Mary F. Fernandez   1998
Alin Deutsch        Daniela Florescu    1998
Alin Deutsch        Alon Y. Levy        1998
Alin Deutsch        Dan Suciu           1998
Mary F. Fernandez   Daniela Florescu    1998
```

Comment: post the `dput(head(data))`. Ie run `dput(your_data)`, copy the results and paste it over here

Comment: This is not working. How can I extract values?

Comment: This is what I get

`c("[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Mary F. Fernandez\", 1998],", "[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Daniela Florescu\", 1998],", 
"[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Alon Y. Levy\", 1998],", "[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Dan Suciu\", 1998],", 
"[\"Mary F. Fernandez\", \"Daniela Florescu\", 1998],")`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strcapture` to get your desired table:

```
proto <- data.frame(Person1 = character(), Person2 = character(), date = integer())
strcapture('([^",]+)\\W+([^",]+)\\W+(\\d+)\\]', string, proto)

            Person1           Person2 date
1      Alin Deutsch Mary F. Fernandez 1998
2      Alin Deutsch  Daniela Florescu 1998
3      Alin Deutsch      Alon Y. Levy 1998
4      Alin Deutsch         Dan Suciu 1998
5 Mary F. Fernandez  Daniela Florescu 1998
```

If you do not understand regex, then you could also do the following:

```
trimws(paste0(string, collapse = ""), white = ",")%>%
  reticulate::py_eval()%>%
  map_df(~setNames(.x, c(c("Person1", "Person2", "date"))))

      # A tibble: 5 x 3
    Person1           Person 2         date
  <chr>             <chr>             <int>
1 Alin Deutsch      Mary F. Fernandez  1998
2 Alin Deutsch      Daniela Florescu   1998
3 Alin Deutsch      Alon Y. Levy       1998
4 Alin Deutsch      Dan Suciu          1998
5 Mary F. Fernandez Daniela Florescu   1998
```

---

```
string <- c("[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Mary F. Fernandez\", 1998],", "[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Daniela Florescu\", 1998],", 
"[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Alon Y. Levy\", 1998],", "[\"Alin Deutsch\", \"Dan Suciu\", 1998],", 
"[\"Mary F. Fernandez\", \"Daniela Florescu\", 1998],")
```